# C#: Unit Testing A double number palindrome with digits

Tags: c#, palindrome

I have been asked to write a test program using a pre made palindrome code. We were told not to fix the code, but to find the problems using a Test. I have spent hours staring at this and I simply need direction.  I've found many things on testing string palindromes and numeric palindromes, none with using digits.  Maybe it's easier than I'm making it on myself, but links or guidance in any way help is much appreciated.

```
public static Boolean isPalindrome(double num)
    {
        if (num >= 10000 && num < 100000)
        {
            double oldNum = num;
            double FirstDig = num % 10;
            num = num - (num % 10);
            double SecondDig = num % 100;
            num = num - (num % 100);
            double ThirdDig = num % 1000;
            num = num - (num % 1000);
            double FourthDig = num % 10000;
            num = num - (num % 10000);
            double FifthDig = num % 100000;
            num = num - (num % 100000);
            FirstDig = FirstDig / 10;
            SecondDig = SecondDig / 100;
            ThirdDig = ThirdDig / 1000;
            FourthDig = FourthDig / 10000;
            FifthDig = FifthDig / 100000;
            double flippedNum = FirstDig + SecondDig + ThirdDig + FourthDig + FifthDig;
            flippedNum = flippedNum * 100000;
            if (flippedNum == oldNum)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use integers instead?

Comment: @Phil1970 Shh...that's the bug the OP is supposed to find. Or at least one of them.

Comment: It would be much simple to convert the value to a string and then verify if it is a palindrome.

Comment: @Phil1970 Did you read the question?

Comment: The arbitrary range does not make sense. If one try 9449 in that code it would return false. If the code does handle to full range, it should probably throw an exception.

Comment: @Phil1970, that's the point. It's a function that doesn't handle all cases correctly. The exercise is to write the tests that expose those issues without modifying the code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well effectively, I was more looking for problems in that code that writing unit tests. But once you know some of the limitation of the code it is easier to write unit tests written specifically to uncover those problems. One problem with this code is that it is sensible to floating point errors and another is that the usable range is limited.

Comment: we are told to not touch this code.  It is not intended to be completely correct.  He wants us to "break" the program by implementing tests on this.  As I stated, I've found nothing on numeric palindromes with digits to even begin to start.  If I hadn't been working on this for many hours I wouldn't be asking for help, so I thank you for your answers already.

Comment: @MrNiceGuy1726 Let's start from the beginning. Do you know what a palindrome is? If not, then you need to learn the definition. If you do, then come up with a few examples and see if the method returns the correct value.

Comment: I don't understand how you say that you found nothing on numeric palindromes. [Google has a lot to say about them](https://www.google.com/search?q=numeric+palindromes&oq=numeric+palindromes&aqs=chrome..69i57.3031j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: The function as written seem to often fails so it is not hard at all to find cases where a palindrome is not detected. Obviously, finding number that are not palindrome reported as palindrome is harder... but not that much. I was able to find that the function report 9 numbers as being palindrome in the supported range (testing only whole numbers) and none of them were palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

Write a unit test that takes a number, passes it to this function, and compares the expected result to the actual outcome. With NUnit3, it could look like this:

```
[TestCase(101d, true)]
[TestCase(100d, false)]
public void SutConfirmsIfNumberIsPalindrome(double input, bool expectedOutcome) {
  var outcome = isPalindrome(input);
  Assert.True(outcome == expectedOutcome);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing tests, the implementation of a method shouldn't matter. Instead, you need to know the expected output for given a input. I suggest making a list of these and then implement a test for each input you can think of. Start simple and as you go more ideas will come and the inputs will be more complex.